# Where can I find the K-means source code in pyspark.ml package?

Tags: apache-spark, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

From the PySpark 2.0.1 documentation,I only can find some code like this :

[the codes from pyspark.ml package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdQOl.png)

These code just assign values to some properties.Where I can find the key python codes to finds out how the algorithm runs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark is primarily implemented in Scala, and PySpark wraps some subset of the API to expose it in Python.  You can find the algorithm's implementation in the [MLLib codebase](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/clustering/KMeans.scala).